# CLIPS How to divide text into word?

Tags: clips

I need to write a method of a function that does the following:

- Divides the text into words;
- Prints words that are different from the first word;
- And before that converts each word according to the following rule:

  *If the word is odd, then removes its middle letter.*

The result is displayed on the screen and in a text file.

Comment: Please, provide the piece of code you have accomplished to write. Also, feel free to check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to post a proper question.

Comment: The fact of the matter is that I do not know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that will give you the list of different words:

```
CLIPS> 
(deffunction munge (?text)
   (bind ?w1 (explode$ ?text))
   (bind ?w2 (create$))
   (progn$ (?w ?w1)
      (bind ?len (str-length ?w))
      (if (oddp ?len)
         then
           (bind ?nw (str-cat (sub-string 1 (div ?len 2) ?w)
                               (sub-string (+ (div ?len 2) 2) ?len ?w)))
           (bind ?w2 (create$ ?w2 ?nw))
         else
           (bind ?w2 (create$ ?w2 (str-cat ?w)))))
    (bind ?first (nth$ 1 ?w2))
    (bind ?rest (rest$ ?w2))
    (bind ?w3 (create$))
    (progn$ (?w ?w2)
      (if (neq ?w ?first)
         then
         (bind ?w3 (create$ ?w3 ?w))))
    ?w3)
CLIPS> (munge "red green blue purple brown green white red black blue")
("gren" "blue" "purple" "brwn" "gren" "whte" "blck" "blue")
CLIPS>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start with some basic documentation.

An example:

> http://www2.cs.siu.edu/~rahimi/cs537/slides/big-2.pdf

You should look at multi-field built-in functions.